# "Could not dynamically require 'binding.node'" when trying to rollup speaker module

Tags: node.js, typescript, rollupjs

I'm trying to use rollup to bundle the [speaker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker) module.

Once it builds and I try to run it, I get the following error:

> Error: Could not dynamically require "/path/to/Project/build/binding.node". Please configure the dynamicRequireTargets or/and ignoreDynamicRequires option of @rollup/plugin-commonjs appropriately for this require call to work.

From the build:

```
const os = require$$0__default$3["default"];
const debug = src.exports('speaker');
const binding = bindings.exports('binding'); // Error occurs here
```

I've tried to add the path and version of it to `dynamicRequireTargets` with no luck. Thing is, there is no `Project/build` folder, so I'm not sure if it only exists during build time or if it's a fake path.

**How can I get this to build and run correctly?**

---

#### Minimal reproducible example

```
$ npm init
$ npm i --save speaker
```

`src/index.ts`

```
import * as Speaker from 'speaker';

console.log(Speaker);
```

`rollup.config.ts`

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import executable from 'rollup-plugin-executable';

import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

const incrementalDependencyLoader = {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: {
    file:
      '/dist/' +
      require(path.join(process.cwd(), 'package.json')).name,
    // cjs translates to CommonJs which is supported by Node
    format: 'cjs',
    banner: '#!/usr/bin/env node\n',
  },
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve(),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: fs.existsSync(path.join(process.cwd(), './tsconfig.build.json'))
        ? './tsconfig.build.json'
        : './tsconfig.json',
    }),
    json(),
    commonjs({}),
    executable(),
  ],
  external: [],
};

// with using an array, we can create multiple bundled javascript files
export default [incrementalDependencyLoader];
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Comment: As a workaround right now, I'm simply using `child_process` with `exec('ffplay -nodisp -ss 5 /path/here')` to play audio.